# Creating simple REST webservice on Eclipse

Tags: json, eclipse, spring, apache, web-services

I am trying to start with a simple web service following the example : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I am unable to get any response when I hit the service URL. The way I am trying to run this is by running the project on Apache web server from Eclipse.
This is my controller:

```
package com.nscm.controller;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.nscm.model.User;

@RestController
public class NSCMController {

    @RequestMapping("/getuser")
    public User getUser()
    {
        System.out.println("NSCMController.getUser()");
        return new User();
    }

}
```

This is my service class:

```
package com.nscm.service;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan("com")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Application.main()");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Even though as the example mentions the web.xml and the spring.xml is not required, even after placing these, my code does not work. None of the SOPs are called when I hit the URL. Please help me if I am missing anything here.

Comment: Have you actually ran the `Application` class? A web.xml doesn't do a thing so it won't help a bit. Also you should annotate your `Application` class with `@Configuration` and please put `com.nscm` into the component scan (it will now scan every package starting with `com` which is a bit overkill imho).

Comment: @M.Deinum, yes I did run the Application class. I am getting an error like this if I do so.
_Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/util/List; from class org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication_

Please note that I am not using maven. I have all the required Spring Jars in the setup. I am expecting the application to be executed in Eclipse the following way:
MYProject > Run as > Run on server > Select Apache and finish